# Impact of Natural Selection on Population Size

Tags: evolution, natural-selection, population-biology, allele

I have conducted a lab with my IB Biology 11 class, regarding changes in allele frequencies within generations overseeing the natural selection of an advantageous phenotype. We were looking to conclude some sort of link between the changing allele frequencies and an overall changing population number of the species. Lab results saw, that as the frequency of the advantageous phenotype increased, the total population dipped and then increased after the 3rd generation. Can anyone point out any possible reasons as to why this occurred - regarding any factors at all? The image below depicts frequency of the advantageous allele vs total population.

[image]

Comment: Can you give more detail because I don't understand?  Was this an experiment or a simulation?  What was the advantageous phenotype and did you know in advance that it would be advantageous ?

In your graph, what is on the x axis and what is on the y axis?

Comment: @remi.b Can you provide some illumination?  I don't understand it.

Comment: @JohnnyToff The question is unclear to me. Your picture does not contain any axis labels, you talk about both population size and allele frequency but I don't understand what connection you're making in between them and I do not understand exactly the pattern you've observed. If you're dealing with population, it is also unclear the population dynamic before the introduction of a mutation and it is unclear whether the mutation was beneficial or deleterious. I am voting to close as unclear.

Comment: Can you add a better image with proper axis labels? Also use imgur to upload your images or use HTML (as I have edited your original post).

Comment: You should always label axes on a graph. I know it's explained in the text, but it's best practice to label your graphs to facilitate understanding of the data you're presenting.

Comment: Related: https://xkcd.com/833/

Answer (score 1):

Take the following thought experiment.

A population off 100 fish, 90 red and 10 blue. On average, a red fish has 0.5 children and a blue fish has 2. This is how the population develops after each generation:

1. 90 red, 10 blue, 100 total, 10% blue
2. 45 red, 20 blue, 65 total, 31% blue
3. 23 red, 40 blue, 63 total, 63% blue
4. 12 red, 80 blue, 92 total, 87% blue
5. 6 red, 160 blue, 166 total, 96% blue

Notice that even though the percentage of blue fish strictly increases, the total population decreases and then increases. This is because the initial population had red fish who died off before the growth of the blue fish become noticeable. I suspect that something similar happened in your experiment, although I cannot say for sure since your description of it was vague.

I also want to make it explicitly clear that having my starting population be more red than blue fish made this effect much larger, but was not necessary. Even if I started with 50 red fish and 50 blue fish, this decrease in population followed by an increase could have still happened. It would have required less clean numbers for the fish reproduction rates, which I did not want to deal with.